# Using a fake mongoDB for pytest testing

Tags: python, pymongo, pytest, fixtures, mongomock

I have code that connects to a MongoDB Client and I'm trying to test it. For testing, I don't want to connect to the actual client, so I'm trying to figure out make a fake one for testing purposes. The basic flow of the code is I have a function somewhere the creates a `pymongo` client, then queries that and makes a dict that is used elsewhere.

I want to write some tests using pytest that will test different functions and classes that will call `get_stuff`. My problem is that `get_stuff` calls `mongo()` which is what actually makes the connection to the database. I was trying to just use `pytest.fixture(autouse=True)` and `mongomock.MongoClient()` to replace `mongo()`.

But this isn't replacing the `mongo_stuff.mongo()`. Is there some way I can tell pytest to replace a function so my `fixture` is called instead of the actual function? I thought making the `fixture` would put my testing `mongo()` higher priority in the namespace than the function in the actual module.

Here is an example file structure with my example:

```
.
├── project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── mongo_stuff
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── mongo_stuff.py
│   └── working_class
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── somewhere_else.py
└── testing
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_stuff.py
```

**mongo_stuff.py**

```
import pymongo

def mongo():
    return pymongo.MongoClient(connection_params)

def get_stuff():
    db = mongo()  # Makes the connection using another function
    stuff = query_function(db)  # Does the query and makes a dict
    return result
```

**somewhere_else.py**

```
from project.mongo_stuff import mongo_stuff

mongo_dict = mongo_stuff.get_stuff()
```

**test_stuff.py**

```
import pytest
import mongomock

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def patch_mongo(monkeypatch):
    db = mongomock.MongoClient()
    def fake_mongo():
        return db
    monkeypatch.setattr('project.mongo_stuff.mongo', fake_mongo)

from poject.working_class import working_class  # This starts by calling project.mongo_stuff.mongo_stuff.get_stuff()
```

And this will currently give me a connection error since the `connection params` in **mongo_stuff.py** are only made to work in the production environment. If I put the `import` statement from **test_stuff.py** into a test function, then it works fine and `mongomock` db will be used in the testing enviornment. I also tried change the `setattr` to `monkeypatch.setattr('project.working_class.mongo_stuff.mongo', fake_mongo)` which also does not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're halfway there: you have created a mock for the db client, now you have to patch the `mongo_stuff.mongo` function to return the mock instead of a real connection:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def patch_mongo(monkeypatch):
    db = mongomock.MongoClient()
    def fake_mongo():
        return db
    monkeypatch.setattr('mongo_stuff.mongo', fake_mongo)
```

#### Edit:

The reason why you get the connection error is that you are importing `somewhere_else` on module level in `test_stuff`, and `somewhere_else` runs connection code also on module level. So patching with fixtures will come too late and will have no effect. You have to patch the mongo client *before* the import of `somewhere_else` if you want to import on module level. This will avoid the error raise, but is extremely ugly:

```
from project.mongo_stuff import mongo_stuff
import mongomock
import pytest

from unittest.mock import patch

with patch.object(mongo_stuff, 'mongo', return_value=mongomock.MongoClient()):

    from project.working_class import somewhere_else


@patch.object(mongo_stuff, 'mongo', return_value=mongomock.MongoClient())
def test_db1(mocked_mongo):
    mongo_stuff.mongo()
    assert True


@patch.object(mongo_stuff, 'mongo', return_value=mongomock.MongoClient())
def test_db2(mocked_mongo):
    somewhere_else.foo()
    assert True
```

You should rather avoid running code on module level when possible, or run the imports that execute code on module level inside the tests (as you already found out in the comments).

Comment: This still isn't working. I think it has to do with the import path, which looks like it's described [here](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch)

Comment: If I do the import inside of a test function it seems to work though.

Comment: Well, you didn't provide any test example so it's pretty much impossible for me to know what you are actually importing in tests and how. If you care to actually provide an example of a test you want to patch, I will adapt the answer with a working patch example. Until then, _it isn't working_ can have only one answer - _you're doing it wrong_.

Comment: I see now what you mean by not working. Unfortunately, you can't patch code on module level with fixtures. They are simply not executed yet. See the updated answer for the workaround.

Comment: Btw, the same problem you are facing is in [this neighbor question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51992496/monkeypatching-not-carrying-through-class-import) (disregard the wrong answer though)