# monkeypatching not carrying through class import

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

I'm trying to test some code using `pytest` and need to change a function from some module. One of my imports also imports that function, but this is failing when I change the method using `monkeypatch`. Here is what I have:

**util.py**

```
def foo():
    raise ConnectionError  # simulate an error
    return 'bar'
```

**something.py**

```
from proj import util

need_this = util.foo()
print(need_this)
```

**test_this.py**

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def fix_foo(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr('proj.something.util.foo', lambda: 'bar')

import proj.something
```

And this raises `ConnectionError`. If I change

**test_this.py**

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def fix_foo(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr('proj.something.util.foo', lambda: 'bar')

def test_test():
    import proj.something
```

Then it imports with the `monkeypatch` working as expected. I've read though [this](http://alexmarandon.com/articles/python_mock_gotchas/) and tried to model my testing from it, but that isn't working unless I import inside of a test. Why does the monkeypatch not do anything if it is just a normal import in the testing file?

Answer (score 1):

That is because the fixture is applied to the test function not the entire code. `autouse=True` attribute just says that it should be used in every test