# How to mock a imported object with pytest-mock or magicmock

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, pytest-mock

I am trying to understand the `mock/monkeypatch/pytest-mock` capabilities.

Let me know if this is possible. If not could you please suggest how I can test this code.

My code structure:

```
/
./app
../__init__.py
../some_module1
.../__init__.py
../some_module2
.../__init__.py
./tests
../test_db.py
```

The `/app/__init__.py` is where my application (a Flask application if it helps) is started along with initializing a database connection object to a MongoDB database:

```
# ...

def create_app():
  # ...
  return app

db_conn = DB()
```

The `some_module1` and `some_module` import the `db_conn` object and use it as part of their functions:

```
## some_module1/__init__.py
from app import db_conn

...
db = db_conn.db_name2.db_collection2

def some_func1():
    data = db.find()
    # check and do something with data
    return boolean_result

...

## some_module2/__init__.py
from app import db_conn

...
db = db_conn.db_name1.db_collection1

def some_func2():
    data = db.find()
    # check and do something with data
    return boolean_result
...
```

In my tests, I want to test if my code works properly based on the data received from the database. 
I want to mock the database, more specifically the `db_conn` object since I don't want to use a real database (which would be a lot of work setting up the environment and maintaining it).

Any suggestions on how I can emulate the `db_conn`?

I've been exploring `pytest-mock` and `magicmock` but I don't think or know how to mock the `db_conn` in my test.

Comment: What is `db_conn.some_configuration1` in your example? Is that just some simplification of a method call (something along the lines of `db_conn.get_db(param_a='foo', param_b='bar')`) for the sake of creating an example or is it really `db_conn`'s property?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply.  I updated the description.  Im using mongo database and the "db_configuration" is meant to be db name and db collection.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the intial question "How to mock a imported object with pytest-mock or magicmock" you can do:

```py
from unittest import mock  # because unittest's mock works great with pytest

def test_some_func1():
    with mock.patch('some_module1.db', mock.MagicMock(return_value=...)) as magicmock:
        result = some_func1(...)
        assert ... e.g. different fields of magicmock
        assert expected == result

# or alternatively use annotations

@mock.patch('some_module2.db', mock.MagicMock(return_value=...))
def test_some_func2():
        result = some_func2(...)
```

note that you do not patch the [actual source of db](http://alexmarandon.com/articles/python_mock_gotchas/)

For your other use case

> I want to mock the database (using a mongo database), more specifically the "db_conn" object

you similarly follow the hints of the link above:

```
mock.patch('some_module1.db_conn', mock.MagicMock(return_value=...))
```

Given that, you will notice in your tests that `db` from `db = db_conn.db_name2.db_collection2' will create another mock object. Calls to that object will be recorded as well. In such a way you will be able to trace history of calls and values assignments as well.

---

Furthermore, see [an example how to pach mongo db.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51994349/1256837)

For testing of Flask apps see [the documentation of flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/testing/). Also [this is a nice explanation as well, and uses DB connections](https://www.patricksoftwareblog.com/testing-a-flask-application-using-pytest/).

As a general hint, like @MikeMajara mentioned - separate your code more into smaller functions that are also easy to test. In tradition to TDD: write tests first, implement later, and refactor (especially DRY!)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are right not testing cases on a real database because it's not unit testing anymore if you are using external dependencies.

There is a possibility [to specify `return-value`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.return_value) and customize it ([different return values on each iteration even](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect)) for `Mock` or `MagicMock` objects.

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch 

from app import db_conn


@patch('app.db_conn.find')
def test_some_func1(db_con_mock):
    ...
    assert ...
```

Keep in mind that in each `patch` you should specify the import path of `db_conn` - **the path where `db_conn` **is used** (I assume it's a different path in each test), not where it is defined.

Answer (score 1):

**Separation of concerns.** Build methods that do one, and only one thing. Even more if you are going with TDD. In your example some_func2 does more than one. You could refactor as follows:

```
def get_object_from_db():
    return db.find()

def check_condition_on_object(obj):
    check something to do with object
    return true or false

def some_func2():
   obj = get_object_from_db()
   check_condition_on_object(obj)
```

With this approach you could easily test `get_object_from_db` and `check_condition_on_object` separately. This will improve readability, avoid bugs, and help detecting these if they appear at some point.

---

**About "mocking an imported object"**. You might be trying to mock an object with a library that is meant for a more advance case than yours. These libraries provide you with a bunch of methods surrounding test environment out of the box that you might not need. From the looks, you just want to populate an object with mock data, and/or interact with a mocked db_connection instance. So...

**To populate**, I would simplify: You know the condition you want to test and you want to check if the result for a given object is the expected one. Just build yourself a `test_object_provider.py` that returns your known cases for `true|false`. No need to make things more complex.

**To use a fake MongoDB connection** you can try with [mongomock](https://github.com/mongomock/mongomock). (although ideally you would test mongo with a real instance in a separate test).