# How to mock a function in another method being called using pytest

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I have the following structure for the project

```
myapp
|
 -contrib
   |
   - helpers.py
 - views
   |
   - app_view.py
```

In `helpers.py` I have the following method

```py
def method(**kwargs) -> int:
    # Some code here
    requests.post(
            url=f"{REMOTE_SERVER}/sc",
            json=kwargs,
            timeout=5
        )
```

In `app_view.py` I have the following implementation. I am calling the method inside a thread and I need to mock it using pytest to check whether it's being called once and called with certain number of parameters.

```py
import myapp.contrib.helpers import method


class Score(MethodView):


    @prepare_req
    def post(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Post Score
        """
        response_data = dict()
        # Some logic here
        self.filter_score(kwargs)

        return jsonify(response_data)

    def filter_score(self, **kwargs)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=method, kwargs=event_data)
        thread.start()
```

Using `pytest` I am trying to mock the `method()` as follows.

```py
def test_score(client, mocker): 
    url = "sc/1.1/score"
    patched_method = mocker.patch(
        "myapp.contrib.helpers.method"
    )

    client.post(url, json=issue_voucher_post_data)
    patched_method.assert_called_once() # <- this is getting false and not mocking the method
```

Tried the below as well but it wont patch properly

```
patched_method = mocker.patch(
        "myapp.views.app_view.method"
    )
```

But it will call the corresponding view

How to mock a function used inside a thread in a view which is available in another module using pytest
?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock a imported object with pytest-mock or magicmock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58377166/how-to-mock-a-imported-object-with-pytest-mock-or-magicmock)